# VB.NET application requests .NET 4.5 even though I built it to use .NET 3.5

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I created an application in VB.NET Visual Studio 2013. I set the target as .NET Framework 3.5 (through Solution Explorer -> Application Properties), but when I rebuild the application and run it in another system, it asks for .NET 4.5 to run the application.

I checked several times, and I have definitely selected only 3.5 in my source.

Comment: Don't abuse the caps lock key please

Comment: I think my eyes are bleeding from reading this.

Answer (score -1):

same problem happened with me 
Use ccleaner  
clean the cache and regex errors  
 
launch vs 2013 again
( PS : before you build the app select 3.5 framework at the start )